# Apache POI custom data format is modified

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to alter an Excel file and put some data in it.
Most of what I try goes well. However my currency formatting is not done 100% correctly...

What I want is my currencies to be format like `€   1.000,43`. So the Euro sign on the left, the amount on the right with dot as thousands separator, comma as the decimal separator and two decimals.

If I do that in Excel and apply this custom formatting rule it works: `"_ [$€-nl-BE] * #.##0,00_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * -#.##0,00_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * \"-\"??_ ;_ @_ "`

So I just copied that rule and apply it through Apache POI:

```
XSSFDataFormat dataFormat = (XSSFDataFormat) workbook.createDataFormat();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("_ [$€-nl-BE] * #.##0,00_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * -#.##0,00_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * \"-\"??_ ;_ @_ "));
```

However that results in something slightly different: `€   1.000,4300`. You can see that it goes well except for the decimals. There are 4 instead of 2...
When I have a look in Excel at the custom formatting it is also slightly different (notice the 4 zeroes): `_ [$€-nl-BE] * #.##0,00000_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * -#.##0,00000_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * "-"?????_ ;_ @_`

So I wonder what could be wrong that somewhere someone (either Apache POI or Excel) do put 4 decimals instead of the 2 that I defined. Notice that if I change it in Excel back to 2 decimals that it showing correct again. Even after saven and closing and reopening the document.

Comment: Does it work with `XSSFDataFormat dataFormat = workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat();` instead of `XSSFDataFormat dataFormat = (XSSFDataFormat) workbook.createDataFormat();`?

Comment: @deHaar No that does not make any difference... So I changed it to this: `XSSFDataFormat dataFormat1 = (XSSFDataFormat) workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat();
        cellStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat1.getFormat("_ [$€-nl-BE] * #.##0,00_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * -#.##0,00_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * \"-\"??_ ;_ @_ "));`

Comment: Does that one work as expected?

Comment: No it does not, same result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Apache poi` creates the `*.xlsx` file as `Excel` would store it. And in the storage the number formats never are localized but always are in `en_US` format. Only the `Excel` `GUI` then localizes the number format.

So for the storage your number format would must be

```
"_ [$€-nl-BE] * #,##0.00_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * -#,##0.00_ ;_ [$€-nl-BE] * \"-\"??_ ;_ @_ "
```

Note decimal separator is `.` and thousands separator is `,` because of `en_US` locale.

If opened in localized `Excel` `GUI` this changes then to the locale specific decimal separator and thousands separator.

But Excel itself also is not storing language tags like `nl-BE` in number formats. Instead it uses the [Windows Language Code Identifier (LCID)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f). This is `813` for `nl-BE`. So using `[$€-813]`, which is the same as `[$€-nl-BE]`, will be better.

Following works for me also in my German `Excel`:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class CreateExcelCustomNumberFormat {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
  CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("_ [$€-813] * #,##0.00_ ;_ [$€-813] * -#,##0.00_ ;_ [$€-813] * \"-\"??_ ;_ @_ "));

  Cell cell = workbook.createSheet().createRow(0).createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue(1000.43);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

This code is tested using current `apache poi 4.1.2` and `Excel 2016`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I did change the thousands and decimal separator but now when I open the Excel it says there are some data problems and that it wants to try to recover from it, when I do so I can see the amounts are not formatted anymore...

Comment: @dirkvranckaert: I gave you a complete example which is tested using current `apache poi 4.1.2` and `Excel 2016`. So I cannot reproducing your problem.

Comment: @dirkvranckaert: You have put the space behind the last underscore in format code? So `dataFormat.getFormat("...;_ @_ ")`? `dataFormat.getFormat("...;_ @_")` will be wrong.

Comment: that was indeed my issue! Thanks for pointing that out to me! :-) It now works!