# Apache POI Customformat(#.##0,00) does not work

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

We are using the apache poi 4.1.2 in our project. I am using the Excel 2013. I'm trying to format the number with Apache poi but this Format(#.##0,00) is not working. My requirement is if the cDecimalSepString is DOT(.), the number should be in Format(#,##0.00). if the cDecimalSepString is Comma(,), the number format should be in Format(#.##0,00). Format(#,##0.00) works for me, but the Format(#.##0,00) is not working. My Excel default Decimal separator(.) and thousand separator is Comma(,).  When the if the cDecimalSepString is Comma(,) If I generate the Excel with Format(#,##0.00) and Change my Excel Decimal separator(,) and thousand separator is Comma(.), then it works.  so my question is we always need to use this Format(#.##0,00) when generate the Excel fie with Apache POI?

```
            CellStyle numStyle = null;
            if (cDecimalSepString != null && cDecimalSepString.equals("."))
            {
                numStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                short format = (short)BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0.00");
                numStyle.setDataFormat(format);
            }
            else
            {
                DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
                numStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                numStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("#.##0,00"));                    
            }
        string value= "1000.43";
        double dValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
        Cell cell = workbook.createSheet().createRow(0).createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(dValue);
        cell.setCellStyle(numStyle);
```

Comment: Try setting a locale at the start of the format? Try setting exactly what you want in Excel, then read it back in Apache POI and see what Excel opted to really store?

Comment: I set the locale,but still it's not working.   Looks like the storage of the number formats never are localized but always are in en_US format. as given below.  how to make it work.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967396/apache-poi-custom-data-format-is-modified                              
Locale.setDefault(locale);
LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(locale);

Comment: Once i set the german locale the number us stored in the format #.##000..Even if i try to set the "#.##0,00" in Excel Cell, its not formatting the Number correctly.

Comment: Figure out how to set it as you need in Excel, then see how Excel stores it. Until you know how to get Excel to do what you want directly in Excel, no point going to POI

Comment: @ Gagravarr, Excel allows to set the excel format #.##0,00 only when i change the Excel options, System settings  Decimal separator(,) and thousand separator as DOT(.). so this format ( #.##0,00) does not work if we have decimal separator(.),thousand separator(,). So Apache POI also fails to set this Number format for the English Locale. Please let me know what do you think.

Comment: If you can't do it in Excel itself then you'll never be able to do it with Apache POI, sorry! POI can only setup the file in ways that Excel supports

Comment: @ Gagravarr, so my solution will be always export the number in the Format(#,##0.00) and the generated Excel file will display the number as per the Excel default settings on the user Machine. It will work.Please let me know whats the default Decimal separator in german OR Eu Excel versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution will be always export the number in the Format(#,##0.00) and the generated Excel file will display the number as per the Excel default settings on the user Machine.